# How to fix error migrating Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::getToken?

Tags: laravel-5

I try to update laravel 5.0 app to 5.7 and moving steps by step I was stopped by error :

```
    Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::getToken() (View: /var/www/html/YoutubeAPI_Demo-57/resources/views/videos.blade.php)

in HtmlServiceProvider.php line 51
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(FatalThrowableError), 1)
```

I found file :

```
vendor/illuminate/html/HtmlServiceProvider.php with method which triggered error: 
    /**
     * Register the form builder instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerFormBuilder()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('form', function($app)
        {
            $form = new FormBuilder($app['html'], $app['url'], $app['session.store']->getToken());

            return $form->setSessionStore($app['session.store']);
        });
    }
```

Can you give a hint how to fix this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `getToken()` with `token()`